# Algorithm to score 'perceived randomness' of different functions

Tags: algorithm, compression, information-theory

I have some functions that take a lowercase letter of the English alphabet as input and return True or False.

There are 2^26 such possible functions.  Below are some functions and their 26-bit representations:

00000000000000000000000001 (z only)
01010101010101010101010101 (even letters only)
10000000000000000000000000 (a only)
10001000100000100000100000 (vowels only)
10000001000000000000000100 (a, h, x only)

What I would like to do is score these functions for perceived randomness, i.e. how arbitrary do they seem to a human?  Does there seem to be a pattern, or did I just pick some letters randomly?

I am thinking the score might be based on quantifying the minimum information you would need to describe the pattern to someone else, or the size of the pattern string when compressed.

Is there an algorithm that would be suited to this?  And can it incorporate extra information a human might also know in advance, e.g. "aeiou" belong to the "vowels" class, "gjpqy" belong to the "low-hanging" class, "bdfhijklt" belong to the "tall" class?

Comment: If you have time to look into the details, you can learn Kolmogorov Complexity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity

Comment: Quantifying perceived randomness is pretty tough. You might be interested in [The perception of randomness](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/019688589190029I). Searching for "perceived randomness" returns lots of interesting results. You'll probably want to understand how people actually perceive randomness before you go about trying to assign a "perceived randomness" value to your sequences.

Comment: I think this is actually more of a psychology problem than a programming problem. And if people are shown the letters instead of the binary, then it involves linguistics too. I can only envisage getting results by trying it out on large numbers of people; how difficult it is to describe the pattern would then indeed be a good test.

Answer (score 1):

You can't determine the randomness of a process with only one sample.  This xkcd comic illustrates this well:

[image: 4 is random]

In fact our universe itself may be inconceivably unlikely, but it only had to happen once.

"Perceived randomness" is a very squishy concept.  You would need to conduct trials with humans and your strings to see what they thought was "random" and what wasn't, and then try to construct a model of that.

You can use things like run-length encoding and a bit-oriented LZ77 type of compression to detect repeated strings, but you're going to have a hard time compressing a string that's only 26 bits long to begin with, no matter what description language you design.  Especially if you try to include things like tallness, vowels, etc.  As a result, the Kolomogorov complexity will not be a good model of human "perceived randomness".

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier 26-bits is a very short dataset, but one suitable measure would be to count "run lengths", for example:

- `01010101010101010101010101`: All run lengths are 1
- `10000001000000000000000100`: Run length 1 occurs three times, 6 occurs once, 15 once and 2 once

You could create a histogram of "typical" run lengths by simulation (or look them up from somewhere) and compare those with these.

It might be worth "inflating" these strings by appending all their rotations like this (I'm using a larger alphabet so this is more clear): `ABCD` would become `ABCD-BCDA-CDAB-DABC`, excluding dashes. From this you get more stats and less boundary effects when the string ends.

---

Edit: On average on long strings the probability of a run-length of `n` should be `O(2^-n)`, but it is still easiest to estimate these by simulation.

Comment: I put together a fiddle implementing this idea.  http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=jd6st4yQ&version=1

Comment: Cool! I never got familiar with R but this visualization helps us to see if we agree with the algorithm's ranking.